# Django add admin settings not related to user view of site

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add some settings to the Django admin interface. In particular I want to have fields set up to allow the administrator to enter POP3 mail settings.

Eg

[ ] Enable mail checking (checkbox)

[***_*__*_*__**] Mail server

[***_*__*_*__**] User name

[***_*__*_*__**] Password

etc

These fields will always exist and are not dependent on anything a front end user would enter.

Documentation seems to only talk about ModelAdmin, which I don't think is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something would go in settings and you want to edit this from the admin. [dbsettings](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) is a django project that allows you to do this.

Since `settings.py` is just plain Python code, you can create your own custom settings and manipulate them from the admin. There are some [guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings) if you do want to create custom settings.

Comment: Thanks, I've gone with django-livesettings for now, but I'll have a read through dbsettings to see what it offers.